# Multimonitor taskbar in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, taskbar

I have an idea to write a multimotor taskbar application in c# for windows xp. So, does anyone have any information how

- to put a taskbar on the second
  monitor,
- to make it use windows styles,
- to prevent aplications running on the
  second monitor to appear in default
  taskbar,
- so on...

Any help would be ...helpful )))

Comment: In case you hadn't found this before, it's been done, and very well in .Net: http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/  this is no small undertaking, so you may want to use an existing solution like this.

Comment: Though this solution is good, it's not opensource and not even free. Also it can’t satisfy my will to do it by myself

Comment: That's all good, just letting you know there are things out there and it's a **huge** undertaking to do what you want, it's not a 2 day project...you'll spend months :)  I just think it's best to at least know that before you get into it is all.

Comment: Nick, thank you for your precaution, but I understand the hugeness of this project rather well. I think this might be a good project for my leisure time, futhermore it seems to me a good way to study winapi.

Comment: I'm using the free MultiMon tool to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can P/Invoke SHAppBarMessage() to create a task bar.  The APPBARDATA.hWnd you'll need could simply be the Handle of a Form class.  Anything goes as far as what you display.

Getting the notifications you'll need to make the task bar display active windows is going to be a whole lot more difficult.  You'll need to use the global WH_SHELL hook, set by SetWindowsHookEx() to receive the notifications you'll need.  You cannot set this hook in C#, it requires an unmanaged DLL that you can inject into a process.  You'll find crucial help in [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WilsonSystemGlobalHooks.aspx).

Getting the Windows taskbar to not do its normal job is going to be impossible unless you somehow find the undocumented information you'll need.  Microsoft doesn't document this for a good reason, the taskbar is an important part of the way they innovate on the Windows look-and-feel.  Quite visible in Win7.  They don't want any code to take a dependency on this, they'd have a near-impossible job of keeping the next version of Windows compatible.  I'd have to recommend you completely disable the Windows taskbar and replace it by your own.